# Two databases with same tables and column names, How to pull out one column with similar data while all the other columns showing the differences?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 databases named **'OK'** and **'TX'** with same table named **'E_Model**' and columns like:
      **'Product_ID' , 'Description', 'Warranty' and 'Category'**
I want to have the list of Product ID's which both the tables have and want to know the difference in all the other column at the same time.

**Desired result** should be like:

```
**'*Database' 'Product_ID' , 'Description', 'Warranty'  'Category'***
OK           LB9456        COFFEE 436      NULL          10      
TX           LB9456         TOASTER 956      1           12
OK           QR3300         APPLE  31        3           15
TX           QR3300         ORANGE 45        5           20
```

I tried to run the following query:

```
SELECT  Product_ID
FROM  OKSV..E_MODEL
INTERSECT
SELECT  Product_ID
FROM  TXSV..E_MODEL
union all
SELECT  Product_ID
FROM  TXSV..E_MODEL
INTERSECT
SELECT  Product_ID
FROM  OKSV..E_MODEL
```

I did get the list of the similar Product_IDs in both the tables of the different databases. but when I used the following query:

```
SELECT  Product_ID, Description, Warranty, Category
FROM  OKSV..E_MODEL
INTERSECT
SELECT  Product_ID,Description, Warranty, Category
FROM  TXSV..E_MODEL
union all
SELECT  Product_ID,Description, Warranty, Category
FROM  TXSV..E_MODEL
INTERSECT
SELECT  Product_ID
FROM  OKSV..E_MODEL
```

It just showed me a different list. Basically, I am trying to know the differences in description, category and warranty of similar product ids in both the tables.
I am doing this so that I could clean the data. I am new to this please help, as I am now doing this one by one which will take a lot of time.

Comment: I rewrote my answer to match your clarified specifications.

Comment: I appreciate that, but didn't worked!

Comment: How did it not work? Did it give an error, or did the data returned not match what you expected?  One thing that will help you get better answers is to fully state how something failed when someone provides a suggestion that didn't work. Sample data is also helpful (it doesn't have to be live data).  Good luck with getting a useful answer.

Comment: Also, StackOverflow recommends that you read [How to ask for help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 'MisMatches'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 49
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Database'.

Comment: There we go - I was missing a close parentheses in my code. Please try again.

Comment: Still showing error :Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 54
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Database'.

Comment: Once more into the breach, my friend. I needed to change the ORDER BY statement to use an ordinal number for the Database column, since that is just an alias for the column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this (now matching your updated specifications). I have two separated CTEs for this as it should make it clearer what I am doing, but the same thing can be done using other queries.

```
WITH TXInfo AS (  -- Get all info from TX DB with ID matches
    SELECT Product_ID,
        Description, 
        Warranty, 
        Category
    FROM  TXSV..E_MODEL
    WHERE Product_ID IN (
        SELECT  Product_ID
        FROM  OKSV..E_MODEL
        INTERSECT
        SELECT  Product_ID
        FROM  TXSV..E_MODEL
        )
),
MisMatches as (  -- Get all info from OK DB with data mismatches
    SELECT  
         om.Product_ID,
         om.Description,
         om.Warranty,
         om.Category
    FROM  OKSV..E_MODEL om
    INNER JOIN TxInfo ti
        ON om.Product_ID = ti.Product_ID
    WHERE om.Description <> ti.Description
        OR om.Warranty <> ti.Warranty
        OR om.Category <> ti.Category
    )

SELECT 'OK' as [Database], -- Select all OK data
    mm.Product_Id,
    mm.Description,
    mm.Warranty,
    mm.Category
FROM Mismatches mm
UNION
SELECT 'TX',  -- Select only TX data that didn't match
    ti.Product_Id,
    ti.Description,
    ti.Warranty,
    ti.Category
FROM TXInfo ti
INNER JOIN Mismatches mm
    ON ti.Product_Id = mm.Product_Id
ORDER BY Product_Id, 
    1 desc -- Will not let us order by the name of the field here.
```